# Optimize Google mobile ad initialization and loading on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-mobile-ads

I am using `google_mobile_ads` Flutter package (version `^3.0.0`) in a Flutter app targeting Android. I am occasionally getting ANRs that could be related to ads.

[This](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/optimize-initialization) article talks about optimizing Google mobile ads initialization and loading on Android as a way to prevent ANRs.

Should I add these options to my Android manifest considering I am using Flutter and not a native Android app that the article is targeting?

```
<manifest>
  ...
  <application>
      ...
      <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.flag.OPTIMIZE_INITIALIZATION"
          android:value="true"/>
     <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.flag.OPTIMIZE_AD_LOADING"
          android:value="true"/>

  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: No need to add that meta-data when you use google_mobile_ads Flutter package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering `google_mobile_ads` Flutter package does use the Google Mobile Ads SDK for Android, those optimizations should apply.

> Is there a downside to using this? Why is this not on by default if it just makes loading better without any potential "side-effects"?

As [described here](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/optimize-initialization), activating those optimizations means the initialization and ad loading tasks that require extended processing time are offloaded to background threads.

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/uhiEH7s14Cg?pli=1) does not mention any drawback, and refer to this ["Get started" guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start).
That means it is not the default only because those optimizations are still in Beta.

The [new testing features for ad inspector](https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/2023/05/announcing-new-testing-features-for-ad.html?m=0&hl=en_AU) announced yesterday can help you validate those optimizations effects.

Answer (score 1):

> One way of doing this is with the variable **isBannerLoaded** along with the **BannerAdListener**.

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AdBanner extends StatefulWidget {
  final String adUnitId;
  final AdSize size;
  const AdBanner({this.adUnitId, this.size});

  @override
  State<AdBanner> createState() => _AdBannerState();

  static AdSize getBannerSize() {
    final width =
        MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size.width;
    final height =
        MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size.height;
    if ((width >= 460 && width <= 500) || (height >= 800 && height <= 900)) {
      return AdSize(width: 336, height: 280);
    } else if ((width >= 360 && width <= 375) ||
        (height >= 600 && height <= 700)) {
      return AdSize(width: 320, height: 100);
    } else if ((width >= 375 && width <= 414) ||
        (height >= 700 && height <= 800)) {
      return AdSize(width: 300, height: 250);
    } else if ((width >= 300 && width <= 360) ||
        (height >= 400 && height <= 600)) {
      return AdSize(width: 320, height: 50);
    } else {
      return AdSize(width: 320, height: 50);
    }
  }
}

class _AdBannerState extends State<AdBanner> {
  bool isBannerLoaded = false;
  BannerAd myBanner;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('AdBanner build : ' + widget.adUnitId);
   
    final BannerAd bannerAd = myBanner;
    if (isBannerLoaded && bannerAd != null) {
      return Container(
          height: bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
          width: bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
          child: AdWidget(ad: bannerAd));
    } else {
      return Container(
      );
    }

   
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    myBanner = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: widget.adUnitId ?? '/234721286/NY_KB_Home_Micrec_23',
      size: widget.size ?? AdSize.banner,
      request: AdRequest(),
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          print('AdBanner onAdLoaded : ' + ad.adUnitId);
          setState(() {
            isBannerLoaded = true;
          });
        },
        // Called when an ad request failed.
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
          print('inside failed');
          // Dispose the ad here to free resources.
          ad.dispose();
          print('failed to load: $error');
        },
        // Called when an ad opens an overlay that covers the screen.
        onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => print('Ad opened.'),
        // Called when an ad removes an overlay that covers the screen.
        onAdClosed: (Ad ad) => print('Ad closed.'),
        // Called when an impression occurs on the ad.
        onAdImpression: (Ad ad) => print('Ad impression.'),
      ),
    )..load();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    myBanner.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: How is this related to the question at all? How is it helpful in any way???

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: @JeremyCaney the answer is not related with the question at all, there is no possible edit that can be done that will make this an answer to the question.